# Single line break in Github flavoured markdown without any extension

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

I am writing README.md for my project that I have created on GitHub. I am having issues with the line breaks. I have gone through the official documentation, but I am not sure how to make a single line break, as single Enter is not recognized as a line break and two Enters make it a new paragraph.

From documentation:
"My basic recommendation for learning how line breaks work is to experiment and discover -- hit  once (i.e., insert one newline), then hit it twice (i.e., insert two new lines), see what happens. You'll soon learn to get what you want. "Markdown Toggle" is your friend."

It mentions about "Markdown Toggle", I googled it but it shows me "Markdown Here" (Markdown Toggle is renamed maybe). But I want to do it without any extension.

Is it possible?

https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ending a line with two or more spaces should work.

```
Use two or more spaces   <-- 2 or more spaces
to create a line break.
```